# Homebrew Error Installing Node 0.10 and NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I tried to switch to an older version of Node from node `5.0.0` to `0.10.40` so I can use sqlite3 in my app. As a result I tapped `homebrew-versions`, found `node010` and ran `brew install homebrew/versions/node010`. Unfortunately I ran into one issue because I didn't unlink my other version of node. Here was my log:

```
==> Pouring node010-0.10.40_1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node010

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node010

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/include/node/ares.h
/usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node/config.gypi
/usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
/usr/local/include/node/node.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
/usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
/usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
/usr/local/include/node/uv.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8.h
/usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
/usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
/usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall homebrew/versions/node010`
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node010/0.10.40_1: 2688 files, 27M
```

In the end I ran `brew link --overwrite node010`
 and it worked, but then I try to run `brew postinstall homebrew/versions/node010`
 so I can install npm and link the two and I get 
`Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` 
from questions I viewed I should remove that folder with 
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`

which I did and then reran the postinstall, but now I get the same `Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` despite there being no folder in that path anymore. Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest to use `nvm` (also in homebrew) to use different Node versions: https://github.com/creationix/nvm .

Comment: Good note. I switched to nvm and haven't had any issues